# Is there a way to make a list of the results gained from a repeat process?

Tags: r, list, repeat

I have used the ADF test in a repeat process and would like to list the test statistics gained in a single list/vector, in order to represent it in a histogram.

I have tried creating an empty list and using the append function to add each test statistic generated to that empty list. But when I run it, it doesn't return anything and the list stays empty.

```
x=0
  repeat{
    B=adf.test(((arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(1.587,-0.6914),ma=c(-1.525,0.7327)),sd=sqrt(0.03204),n=50))),alternative=c("stationary"),k=5)
    TestStat1=(B$statistic)
    ADF_LIST=append(adf_list, TestStat1, after = length(TestStat1))
    x=x+1
    if(x==10){
      break
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please make your post reproducible by *explicitly* including any non-base R library dependences. Where does `adf.test` come from? Multiple packages seem to provide a function `adf.test`. Secondly, dynamically growing a vector/`list` is often not a very performant way of doing things in R. I would do something like this using `replicate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment above, this is what I would do (I assume `adf.test` is from `tseries`)

```
set.seed(2018)
library(tseries)
adf_list <- replicate(10, adf.test(
    arima.sim(
        model = list(ar = c(1.587, -0.6914), ma = c(-1.525, 0.7327)),
        sd = sqrt(0.03204),
        n = 50))$statistic,
    simplify = F)
adf_list
#[[1]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -2.972603
#
#[[2]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -2.317256
#
#[[3]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -3.235755
#
#[[4]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#     -3.89434
#
#[[5]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -1.897195
#
#[[6]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#     -3.15147
#
#[[7]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -2.723526
#
#[[8]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#     -2.07447
#
#[[9]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -2.193647
#
#[[10]]
#Dickey-Fuller
#    -2.197571
```

As you can see, `replicate(n, expr, simplify = F)` repeatedly evaluates `expr` `n` times and stores results in a `list`. There is no need to manually grow/append a `list`.

If you prefer an array you can remove `simplify = F` (or set `simplify = T`, which is the default).

---

### Update

To show a histogram you could do something like this (I've increased the number of simulations to 100 and am using `ggplot2` for the plotting)

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2018)
replicate(100, adf.test(
    arima.sim(
        model = list(ar = c(1.587, -0.6914), ma = c(-1.525, 0.7327)),
        sd = sqrt(0.03204),
        n = 50))$statistic) %>%
    data.frame(B = .) %>%
    ggplot(aes(B)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 40)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that has helped massively. Is there a way to put those values into a histogram? When I try it says x must be numeric.

Comment: @bigdickeyfuller Sure, I've added an example using `ggplot2` (which I prefer over base R plotting). Please take a look.

Comment: Sorry again, my script is returning - Error in replicate(100, adf.test(arima.sim(model = list(ar = c(1.587,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Never mind, I just installed magrittr, thank you for your help.

Comment: @bigdickeyfuller You're very welcome. Alternatively you may want to install `tidyverse` (`tidyverse` includes `magrittr`, `dplyr`, `ggplot2` and a whole bag of other goodies). Since you're new to SO: Please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for other SO users to identify relevant questions. It also grants a small rep award to both the original poster and the person answering the question.